Lord Vile & Bayes Theorem
Here is a problem I was doing recently for practice:
Lord Vile drinks his whisky randomly, and the probability that, on a
given day, he has n glasses equals $\frac{e^{−1}}{n!}$. Yesterday his wife Lady Vile, his son Liddell and his butler decided to murder him. If he had no whisky that day, Lady Vile was to kill him; if he had exactly one glass, the task would fall to Liddell, otherwise the butler would do it. Lady Vile is twice as likely to poison as to strangle, the butler twice as likely to strangle as to poison, and Liddell just as likely to use either method. Despite their efforts, Lord Vile is not guaranteed to die from any of their attempts, though he is three times as likely to succumb to strangulation as to poisoning.
Today Lord Vile is dead. What is the probability that the butler did it?
Let D = event that Lord Vile Dies, Poi = event that he is poisoned, St = event that he is strangled, L = event that the lady kills, B = event the Butler kills, S = event that son kills.
From the information in the passage, we know:
$$\Pr(\text{St}|\text{L}) = \frac{1}{3}, \Pr(\text{Poi}|\text{L}) = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$\Pr(\text{St}|\text{B}) = \frac{2}{3}, \Pr(\text{Poi}|\text{B}) = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\Pr(\text{St}|\text{S}) = \Pr(\text{Poi}|\text{S}) = \frac{1}{2}$$
Let $\Pr(\text{D}|\text{Poi}) = r$, which means that $\Pr(\text{D}|\text{St}) = 3r$.
We want to find $\Pr(\text{B}|\text{D})$, which, by Bayes' Theorem is $\Pr(\text{D}|\text{B}) \times\frac{ \Pr(B) }{ P(D)}$.
I am struggling to understand how to find $\Pr(D|B)$?
My first attempt was that $\Pr(D|B) = \Pr(D \cap St|B) + \Pr(D \cap P|B) = \frac{\Pr(D \cap St \cap B)}{\Pr(B)} + \frac{\Pr(D \cap P \cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$, but here I got stuck.
My professor had written, that the following equation could be useful: $\Pr(A \cap B | C) = P(B|C) \times P((A|B)|C)$, but I don't see, firstly, why this equality must be true, and secondly, how to apply it in this case.
Elsewhere, a calculation shows that $\Pr(D|B) = 3r \times \frac{2}{3} + r \times \frac{1}{3}$, which seems to be $\Pr(D|ST) \times \Pr(St|B) + \Pr(D|P) \times \Pr(\text{Poi}|B)$, but I am not sure why this expression equals $\Pr(D|B)$.
Any clarification on how to solve the $\Pr(D|B)$ would be appreciated?

$P((A\mid B)\mid C)$ is nonsensical.  You require: $\mathsf P(A&B\mid C) = \mathsf P(B\mid C)\cdot\mathsf P(A\mid B& C)$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

On a sort of side note: Please edit your post to write something like $p_n = \frac{e^{-1}}{n!}$, yielding $p_n = \frac{e^{-1}}{n!}$. The "e-1/n!" that's there doesn't make any sense, since it's greater than $1$ for $n = 0$ or $n = 1$ no matter how you parse it.

In the future, please typeset your mathematics using MathJax. Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. Otherwise, your question is actually erroneously written. ¶ See How to Ask a Good Question for more details.

You want to use the Law of Total Probability, and the presumption that lethality and "who did it" are conditionally independent for a given method.   [IE: that the probability of death from strangulation does not depend on who makes the attempt; for some reason, et cetera]
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(D\mid B) & =\mathsf P(D\mathop\&\operatorname{Str}\mid B)+\mathsf P(D\mathop\& \operatorname{Poi}\mid B) &&\text{LoTP}\\[1ex]& =\mathsf P(D\mid \operatorname{Str}\mathop\& B)\,\mathsf P(\operatorname{Str}\mid B)+\mathsf P(D\mid \operatorname{Poi}\mathop\& B)\,\mathsf P(\operatorname{Poi}\mid B)&&\text{Definition of Conditioning}\\[1ex]& =\mathsf P(D\mid \operatorname{Str})\,\mathsf P(\operatorname{Str}\mid B)+\mathsf P(D\mid \operatorname{Poi})\,\mathsf P(\operatorname{Poi}\mid B)&&\text{Conditional Independence}\\[1ex] &= 3r\cdot(2/3)+r\cdot(1/3)&&\text{The Provided Values}\\[1ex]&= 7r/3\end{align}$

For any (non-null measure) events, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, we have:
$\quad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\mathop\& Y\mid Z) &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X\mathop\& Y\mathop\& Z)}{\mathsf P(Z)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X\mid Y\mathop\& Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mathop\& Z)}{\mathsf P(Z)}\\[1ex] &=\mathsf P(X\mid Y\mathop\& Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)\end{align}$
And when $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\mid Y\mathop\& Z)&=\mathsf P(X\mid Y)\end{align}$
